What movie or show features a scene with a scientific commercial/training video on Eye Wash Stations?
This morning, I got a little shampoo in my eyes in the shower and it reminded me of a scene in a TV show or a movie, where an adult male character was being paid to be in a scientific instructional commercial or training video that showed how to use an emergency eye wash station. The character was afraid of it and couldn't do it, and acted like a child about it. Does anyone have any insight into what TV show or movie this might be from? 

Was in English.
Live action and in color.
I feel like this was made recently (i.e. post 2000).
Most likely made in the U.S. or Canada.
Most likely a TV show, but could have been movie. 


Do you mean this scene from The Office?
It's from 'Paper Airplanes' (season 9, episode 20). From the recap:

Andy Bernard (Ed Helms) prepares for a potential acting job in a laboratory safety video that was arranged by his talent agent, Carla Fern (Roseanne Barr). He takes the job too seriously, treating it as if he were an established movie actor. However, when it comes time to shoot a scene using an eye wash, he has a breakdown after getting yelled at and scolded by Carla. 

Loved the association story, BTW. :) Hope you got it all out.
